# Error: Well-know object must derive from the MarshalByRefObject

Tags: c#

I'm doing a application with 3-tier, I created server by Window Service and it runs without errors, but the client has an error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFyiY.png). Please help me solve it. Thanks

Comment: Please don't link to images. Put the error message in your question: (a) it makes it easier for Google to find it; and (b) it means that if the image link dies the question is still useful.

Comment: Note that you can press Ctrl+C to copy the text of a Windows message box to the clipboard. This works with standard message boxes and also with the one you have in your image.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your service could be using .NET Remoting.

If this is the case then any client which connects to that service must have a definition of the shared service which inherits from MayshalByRefObject.

I would suggest you read [this Microsoft document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) to see if this applies.

Without detailed code to review it is difficult to give you the correct answer, we would need to know

- How the server is implemented
- How the client is implemented

So we can properly determine what your issue could be.